# Where can I find a DOM parser?

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping

I need to read some content from a html page.
I've tested [`simple_html_dom`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm), but it simply isn't usable for what I need it for.

I need something like this (pseaudo syntax based on simple_html_dom):

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$html_obj = parse_html($html);

$title = $html_obj->get('title');
$meta1 = $html_obj->get('meta[name=description]', 'innertext']; //text only
$meta2 = $html_obj->get('meta[name=keywords]', 'innertext']; // text only
$content = $html_obj->get('div[id=section_a]', outerText); //html code
```

I've tested simple_html_dom in so many ways, and only managed to get parts of what I need.
It simply isn't "simple".

I've also tested PHP [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://DOMDocument%3a%3aloadHTML), but it I run in to problems dealing with inline `<script>`.

Are there any php librarys that makes it as easy to get content as in `jQuery`?

**Update**

One of my problems is a a piece of 3rd party javascript from an add agency:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      <!--
        if (window.adgroupid == undefined) {
          window.adgroupid = Math.round(Math.random()*100000);
        }
        document.write('<scr'+'ipt language="javascript1.1" type="text/javascript" src="http://adserver.adtech.de/addyn|3.0|994|3159100|0|-1|size=980x150|ADTECH;loc=100;target=_blank;key=startside,kvinner, kvinnesak, bryllup, graviditet, mamma, kosmetikk, markedsplass, dagbok, feminisme;grp='+window.adgroupid+';misc='+new Date().getTime()+'"></scri'+'pt>');
      //-->
      </script>
```

Even if I change `<scr'+'ipt` to `<script` it gives me invalid javascript code.

Comment: Server side DOM libraries typically use XPath rather than the pseudo-css selection that jQuery uses. I believe the selection would end up something like `//meta[@name="description"]`

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'problems'?

Comment: @Digital Precision, see my updated text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DOMDocument with DOMXPath ..

```
<?php
$DOMDocument = new DOMDocument();
//libxml_use_internal_errors ( true ) ;
$DOMDocument->loadHTMLFile ( 'http://www.iconfinder.com' ) ;
$XPath = new DOMXPath( $DOMDocument );

$title = $DOMDocument->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $title ;

#$desc = $XPath->query('//meta[@name=description]')->item(0)->getAttribute ( 'content' );
#$keywords = $XPath->query('//meta[@name=keywords]')->item(0)->getAttribute( 'content' );
#$content = $XPath->query('//div[@id=section_a]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: see updated question. I'm not able to laod the html code because of the inline javascript. Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

PHPQuery (http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) allows you to manipulate HTML through a jquery like syntax

Comment: +1 I've used PHPQuery in the past and love its familiarity.